# How do I keep a < div > 100 pixels from the top of a page, no matter where the page is scrolled to?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a website with a < div > box (chat box) that pops up whenever the website owner decides to begin a conversation with one of his visitors. The way it is now, a visitor may have scrolled several pages down before the chat box pops up, and then the chat box is hidden! How can I make it so that the chat box always pops up within the visible area of the page?

I use jQuery to poll the server, and load the box when needed.

```
#chatBox {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 200;
  width: 400;
  height: 200;
  background-color: #8596C1;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #BDDEFF #14285F #14285F;
  display: none;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7):

```
.chat_container { position: fixed; top: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 5):

That can be done by applying a `position: fixed` style.
[Doesn't work in IE6 though](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28), you'd need a Javascript fallback if you care enough.

Comment: @Michael: You'd be surprised, sadly.

Comment: @Michael, I'd be happy if the answer is 'none'.

Comment: When I change the position to 'fixed', the box appears all the way in the top left corner (ignores 'top' and 'left') and doesn't scroll with the viewport. It also ignores the z-index and puts it behind other elements...

Comment: @Micheal That's hard to answer without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @Micheal Can't see the problem, the chatbox neither shows up nor is it `fixed`. Great hairdo though. :o)

Comment: That's my boss :) It doesn't show up until you do a search and then I respond to it. jQuery polls the server and toggles the display when there is a new message for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add one more attribute to this work on every possible page.

Along with `position:fixed` and `top:100px` you need to add `z-index:99999` which will help the chat box stay on the top of the page even with some elements which already set the z-inex attributes.

Comment: z-index only works when I use postion "absolute". When I switch to "fixed", it always goes to the back, even though I haven't changed z-index.